# Notification observer called multiple times even though the observer is removed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

When the app is in background mode or phone is in sleep state and a VoIp push is received the below function in AppDelagte directs the user (to the `UserTableViewController` in the app) and posts a notification.

A notification observer in viewDidLoad of the `UserTableViewController` observes the notification and calls the `func simulateMyIncomingCallFromNotification`.

I noticed that when I send a VoIP push  the second time the `func simulateMyIncomingCallFromNotification` is called twice and on the third time, thrice and so on. How can I avoid multiple calls ?

Other SO answers, advised to remove the Notification observer, which I am doing even before setting one, as you can seen in the below extension, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem.

How could I resolve this issue ?

**In AppDelegate:**

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {

 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "User", bundle: nil)

 VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserTableViewController") as! UserTableViewController

 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = VC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("didReceiveIncomingVoipPush"), object: nil, userInfo: payloadDict)
}
```

**In UserTableViewController**

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    func setObserver(_ observer: AnyObject, selector: Selector, name: NSNotification.Name, object: AnyObject?) {
        print("NotificationCenter.default before: \(NotificationCenter.default)")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer, name: name, object: object)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer, selector: selector, name: name, object: object)
        print("NotificationCenter.default after: \(NotificationCenter.default)")
    }
}

fun viewDidLoad(){

NotificationCenter.default.setObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.simulateMyIncomingCallFromNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("didReceiveIncomingVoipPush"), object: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking the question with the "even though" clause. Spot on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple recommends that observers should be registered in `viewWillAppear` and unregistered in `viewWillDissapear`.

Can you try like this.

Answer (score 2):

Getting multiple calls on notifications is probably the case that your controller is not being de-initialised and each time you are adding a new observer to new instance of that controller. 
What you can do:

Add breakpoint on that method and try `print(self)` and see the address of multiples calls.

or just add

```
 deinit() {
    print(self)
 }
```

and check whether that class is being deinitilized or not.

And if thats not the case you can try @[Himanth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445374/5090735) solution.

Comment: `Add breakpoint or deinit() on that method` on which method ?

Comment: the method that is called multiple times simulateMyIncomingCallFromNotification

Answer (score 2):

In my case `Notification` is calling the **number of time** i'm appearing in same screen and which is caused to triggered **same action** X **numberofTime i'm entered to screen**. So I've removed `Notification` observer in `viewWillDisappear` which is actually worked and ***stopped the multiple time triggered action/methods in same screen***.

Thanks to [Himanth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445374/11077258)'s answer i've figured it out

- **Swift4**

> `addObserver`

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.yourNotificationAction(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("yourNotificationName"), object: nil)

}
```

> `removeObserver` when screen is disappear

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("yourNotificationName"), object: nil)
      
    }
```